# make div fill out entire page

Tags: css

I have this page http://xn--e-nsker-r1a.dk and I have body and html 100%, also #site_main with height 100%, but still the #footer is some space from the bottom on screens with high enough resolution. How can I make the body and site_main fill the ENTIRE height of the screen, to make the #footer stick to the bottom, no matter the height (in pixels) of the page.

Not using `fixed`. The Footer should not be visible at all times, only if the page is scrolled down far enough.

Comment: thats a wild looking domain name

Comment: @david It’s IDNA encoding for “e-øsker.dk”. While Firefox, Opera, and Safari decode these according to a per-TLD policy, Chrome decodes them according to the user’s preferred language.

Comment: So to be clear, should the footer always be off the bottom of the screen, even when the vertical resolution is extremely high?

Comment: negative, I've implemented a half fix to make the footer go outside of the screen on low res screens, but right now blank white space may appear beneath the footer if the res is high enough, I want the footer to be at the bottom always, with no white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a sticky footer? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: was just about to post that, but i think the OP only wants the footer to appear if scrolled down far enough